Dataset key name autocomplete
I am working with a large dataset with over 100 keys. When writing queries, I would like to get autocompletion for the key names. My current approach is:
keys = {"POSITION", "CHAN", "SAMPLEDATE", "SAMPLESIZE", "SAMPLEID", 
   "RAWVALUE", "PRODEQP1", "PRODEQP2", "MEASEQP"};
list = Join[{keys}, RandomReal[{1, 100}, {5, 9}]];
ds = Dataset[AssociationThread[First@list, #] & /@ Rest@list]

Current solution is to use the resource function AddCompletion
ResourceFunction["AddCodeCompletion"]["F"][keys]

When I write F[" autocompletion appears as in picture

However, there must be an easier way? That doesn't require typing F[" ?
Best regards
